# Java Array Error Array Table

Tags: java

Why is this happening, why isnt it giving me ***ThisIsWhatItShouldBe**

**Code**

```
class ArreyTable{ 
    public static void main(String OKM[]){              
        System.out.println("Index\tValue");         
        int px[] = {144,240,360,480,720};               
        for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){           
            System.out.println(counter + "\t" + px);        
        }           
    }
}
```

**cmd Result**

```
Index     Value
 0         [I@7852e922 
1          [I@7852e922 
2          [I@7852e922 
3          [I@7852e922 
4          [I@7852e922
```

**ThisIsWhatItShouldBe**

```
Index   Value
0          144
1          240
2          360
3          480
4          720
```

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the entire array instead of the relevant element of it, which you can access by the `[]` operator:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){
    System.out.println(counter + "\t" + px[counter]);
    // Here ------------------------------^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code block

```
for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){           
    System.out.println(counter + "\t" + px);        
}
```

You are each time converting the array `px` to a string, which is `[I@7852e922` for internal JVM reasons.

You have to indicate the *index*  on the array:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){           
    System.out.println(counter + "\t" + px[counter]);        
}
```

That will give the desired result.

Additionally you could replace the `println` with a `printf`:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){           
    System.out.printf("%2d: %3d%n", counter, px[counter]);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this line :
 System.out.println(counter + "\t" + **px[counter]**);

So it will know what value to return ;)

Answer (score 0):

You were originally printing the entire px array object. What was being printed was the output of the toString() function of the array object.

Object.toString() method returns a string, composed of the name of the class, an @ symbol and the hashcode of the object in hexadecimal.

when you use px[counter], it references to the element value at that index.

Correct solution would be:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<px.length; counter++){           
        System.out.println(counter + "\t" + px[counter]);        
    }
```